# Batch file to find a file, create a copy in the same location and run this on multiple directories

Tags: recursion, copy, backup, xcopy, robocopy

here's what I am trying to do.

I have a few hundred users My Documents folders in which most(not all) have a file(key.shk for shortkeys program). 
I need to upgrade the software but doing so makes changes to the original file. 
I would like to run a batch file on the server to find the files in each My Docs folder and make a copy of it there called backup.shk
I can then use this for roll back.

The folder structure looks like this
userA\mydocs
userB\mydocs
userC\mydocs

My tools are xcopy, robocopy or powershell

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This powershell script works... save as .ps1

```
Function GET-SPLITFILENAME ($FullPathName) {

$PIECES=$FullPathName.split(“\”) 
$NUMBEROFPIECES=$PIECES.Count 
$FILENAME=$PIECES[$NumberOfPieces-1] 
$DIRECTORYPATH=$FullPathName.Trim($FILENAME)
$baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.fullname)
$FILENAME = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.fullname)
return $FILENAME, $DIRECTORYPATH

}



$Directory = "\\PSFS03\MyDocs$\Abbojo\Insight Software"
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Recurse | where{$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | % {
   $details = GET-SPLITFILENAME($_.fullname)
   $name = $details[0]
   $path = $details[1]
   copy $_.fullname $path$name"_backup".txt 
}
```